# Mongoose - Subdocument, can not manually populate / set ref field

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a schema with a sub-document like so:

```
User: {
  events: [{
    sender: {
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }
  }]
}
```

Now say I retrieve the child sub document and I already have the 'sender' retrieved from the db, I can not manually set it, here is what I mean:

```
var sender = User.findBy.... // I retrieve the sender
var event = user.events.id(id); // I retrieve the event by ID for the current user

// Now I want to do this but it doesn't work
event.sender = sender; // does not assign, it still remains an ObjectId
```

I wanted the above to basically to do the population myself manually as it does not seem that mongoose supports populating a **single** sub-document instance (please correct me if I am wrong and there is a way).

I know it can populate the whole array of events, but I just need to do it for one instance, no need to for the overhead of populating all events in the array.

Answer (score 1):

For people having the same issue as me. This feature is now supported in mongoose 4.0.

For those on 3.x or below, there isn't really a proper alternative solution, but can be partially achieved by converting the object to a plain JSON object.

Either by **.toObject()** or **.toJSON()** and then doing the assignment.
However note that you will loose the mongoose functionality, so only do this if it is purely just before returning to the client.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to populate it manually just do:

```
User.findOneById(sender, function(err, foundSender) {
    event.sender = foundSender;
});
```

Comment: That is what I did, if you look at my example above, which doesn't work, the assignment isn't accepted by the mongoose object.